# setInterval is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an `span` element. When hovering it, I expected it to change to `hello1 -> hello2 -> hello3` every 1 second, but it is not working like that, why?

```js
i = 0;
$('div').on('mouseenter', function() {
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        $('div').html('<span>hello' + i +'</span>');
          i++;
    }, 1000)

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><span>hello</span></div>
```

Comment: Because `mouseenter` will only trigger once meaning your interval function is only called once. *just a guess*

Comment: Try incrementing `i` inside interval function...

Comment: @JoaquínO is right about where `i` needs to be incremented. You also need to cancel the interval on `mouseleave` or else :)

Comment: Maybe setting two functions to deal with moveover/mouseout to enable/disable the interval? I think that would be an easy fix but not 100% sure why your current function is behaving as it is. 'Hence posting in the comments section'

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/e66vsmmn/ give some width and height to that div... if you comment css, undesired behavior can be seen again... Also, strange behavior is visible when you hovering over SPAN - which is inline element, so, maybe that is problem... (mouseenter loose focus:))

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/e66vsmmn/2/ hm... interesting... now working fine (when you hover over span, too), i'm using text() instead html()... don't have exact explanation, but it is definitely related to creating of html elements by jquery, and css (?) properties of created elements...

Answer (score 3):

Your `i` is incremented outside the `setInterval` meaning it will only increment on `mouseenter`. You should also clear the interval each time you `mouseenter` to avoid lots of intervals going at the same time

```js
i = 1;
var interval;
$('div').on('mouseenter', function() {
  clearInterval(interval);
  interval = setInterval(function() {
    $('div').html('<span>hello' + i + '</span>');
    i++;
  }, 1000)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><span>hello</span>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wt73c6bs/

Alternatively if you want the code to only increment on hover and to reset when you stop hovering use the following

```js
i = 1;
var interval;
$('div').hover(function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = setInterval(function() {
      $('div').html('<span>hello' + i + '</span>');
      i++;
    }, 1000)
  },
  function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
    i = 1;
    $('div').html('<span>hello</span>');
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><span>hello</span>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wt73c6bs/1/

Comment: You could also bind it using `jQuery.one()` and forget about `clearInterval()`

Comment: Yeah you are right, I'll leave it how it is for now though because if you want to do anything else on `mouseenter` this way is more extensible

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use **.append()** instead of **.html()**

```
i = 1;
var interval;
     $('div').on('mouseenter', function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = setInterval(function() {
    $('div').append('<span>hello' + i + '</span>');
    i++;
   }, 1000)
})


 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><span>hello</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple version with pure JavaScript!

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>STACK OVERFLOW TESTS</title>
    <style>

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <span>Hello 0</span>

    <script>
        var innerNumber = 0; // The number that will increments.

        var span = document.querySelector('span'); // Adding some reference to the element and event handlers.
        span.addEventListener('mouseover', setInterval(changeText, 1000));


        function changeText(){
            span.innerHTML = 'Hello ' + (innerNumber + 1); // Obtaining the content of the element and adding 1.
            innerNumber = innerNumber + 1;        
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```